# Assuming my json file is in a server, how do I filter using component did mount in a class setting

Tags: react-native, object, navigation, render, text-rendering

How do I filter my `componentDidMount` data without it throwing an error, filter is not supported in `componentDidMount`

this is my code currently :

```
componentDidMount() {   //fetch data from json server

    fetch("http://0.0.0.0:8001/shopData")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      //console.log(data) 
       item = data.filter(item =>{
          item.id === shopid
      })
      this.setState({item :data})
      
    
      console.log(itemArray)
     
    })
    .catch(err => {  
      console.log("Error loading data" + err);
    });
  }

render(){
    
    item =this.props.navigation.getParam('item'); 
    
    shopid= item.shop_id;

    console.log(this.state.shopData)

    
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>The title </Text>
             <Text>{shopid}</Text>
              <Text>{item.name} </Text>
            
        </View>

}
```

When I run my code, it just gives an empty array. I need to component did mount and retrieve it from this server :fetch("http://0.0.0.0:8001/shopData") so changing it to a static file is not an option. Can anyone provide insight on why my filter isn't working? thanks. For `shopid`, I retrieve it from a previous screen using `this.props` in the render section but I believe it should still be able to pass the value to `componentDidMount` because I am able to log the value gotten

Answer (score 0):

To filter an object, for each element you have to return either true or false. I see that you probably missed that point in here:

```
item = data.filter(item =>{
// You have to return boolean, else it always returns undefined
// which is assumed as false, gives you an empty list
      return item.id === shopid 
})
```

or

```
//if you use arrow without curly braces it's going to return the value
item = data.filter(item => item.id === shopid)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter